# How can I prevent Facebook Connect From Logging out from Facebook.com?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using Facebook connect with php library  when I use

```
FB.Connect.logout();
```

it's log the user out from my website but also it is logging him out from facebook.com

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Are you using facebook connect as part of the login process to your site? Are you also using  requireSession on page load?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't try and do that.

Connect is a single sign on solution - if you log out anywhere you also log out on facebook and all affiliated sites.

You do have an option of forgetting about Facebook after the login has succeeded if you rely on your own cookies to persist a session, but in that case you can't use their logout buttons or javascript and you won't pick up if a user logs out of Facebook.

If you avoid doing auto-login/auto-logout you won't pick up if the user logs out of facebook, so using facebook connect features without re-checking the session status may fail.